# Why do enumeration constants have no linkage?

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer, extern

I'm trying to understand linkage of `enumeration constant`s and could not find a clear answer in the Standard `N1570`. `6.2.2(p6)`:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to
>   be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared
>   to be a function parameter; a block scope identifier for an object
>   declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`.

So I need to understand that constants are not objects. Object is defined as `3.15`:

> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

Also `6.2.2(p4)` (emphasize mine):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in
>   a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31)
>   if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the
>   linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the
>   linkage specified at the prior declaration. **If no prior declaration is**
>   **visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the**
>   **identifier has external linkage**.

Anyway `6.4.4.3(p2)`:

> An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type `int`.

Combining all that I don't understand why

```
enum test {
    a = 1
};

extern int a; //compile-error. UB?
```

does not compile? I expected `a` to have external linkage.

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed647e1293b9e1a3)

Is the behavior well-defined? Can you provide a reference to the Standard explaining that?

Comment: your question does not make any sense. You just try to have two same symbols in the same compilation unit.

Comment: @P__J__ _your question does not make any sense_ Why? I provided the behavior and asked its explanation? Is it well-defined/undifened/unspecified behavior?

Comment: It same as  `int a; extern int a;` why this do not compile.  It is exactly the same two same symbols in one compilation unit. It does not have anything in common with the linkage.

Comment: It is very well specified behavior. You cant have same two identifiers  in one compilation unit.

Comment: @P__J__ `int a; extern int a;` is unrelated here. It is well-defined example specified at `6.9.2(p4)`.

Comment: You do not understand. Linkage does not matter. You have same two names in **one** compilation unit. another example `static int a; /*no linkage*/ extern int a;`

Comment: @P__J__ This is, again, unrelated example which is also defined at `6.9.2(p4)`. What do you mean by /* no linkage */. `a` has internal linkage there.

Comment: Linkage is not important before the **linking**. You do not get there for the reason I have explained

Comment: Something can have an identifier without being an object. Enumeration constants are in the same category as integer constants `123` and character constants `'A'`.

Comment: @Lundin Since an enumerator is not an object it has no linkage. `extern int a` has external linkage. _if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage_ implies that `a` has external linkage. What's wrong about that?

Comment: @SomeName No, it doesn't have _no linkage_, which is a specific term. Rather, linkage doesn't even apply. 6.2.2 is about linkage of objects and functions. You should rather look at 6.2.3, name spaces of identifiers.

Comment: @Lundin _linkage doesn't even apply_ I cannot agree on that. `6.2.2(p6)` states: `The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than an object or a function`. enumerator is "not an object or a function" implying that enumerators have no linkage.

Comment: @Lundin I don't see how `6.2.3` is relevant. It mentiones that `all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants)` has the same namespace.

Comment: @SomeName If you do not agree you need to write your own compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 6.2.2 4, the standard intends to discuss linkage only for identifiers of objects and functions, but it fails to make this clear.

Enumeration constants are mere values, not objects or functions, and their identifiers never have any linkage.

Observe the declaration `extern int a;` declares `a` as an identifier for an `int` object. An `int` object is a different thing from an `int` value, so an enumeration constant named `a` cannot be the same thing as an `int` object named `a`. So the declaration of `extern int a;` is invalid even before linkage is considered.

Comment: Actually I did not find that thr linkage concept applies only to objrcts or functions.

Answer (score 9):

> An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type int

that doesn't means it is a variable of type int

but

> ```
> extern int a;
> ```

says there is a variable of type *int* named *a*, this is a conflict with the enumeration constant

---

> Why does not enumeration constant have no linkage

for the same reason the constant 123 (also having type *int*, but whatever) has no linkage too

Comment: Can you give a reference? Is it well-defined or undefined behavior?

Comment: @bruno you try to answer the wrong question. Linkage is not important. He just has two same symbols in the same compilation unit. I will not compile

Comment: @P__J__ yes I know, this is why I said there is conflict. But I think you do not understand his question, visibly he imagined the enumeration constant has a linkage and `extern int a;` in an other file allows to access to it

Comment: This is in another stage linking. Nothing to do with compiler :)

Answer (score 2):

Linkage does not matter here. In the same compilation unit you try to have two same identifiers  Imagine if the code compiles:

```
enum test {
    a = 1
};

extern int a; 


int b = a;   // which `a`? a as the external variable or `a` as a constant? How to decide.
```

[image]

Comment: So what does this mean: _if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage_?

Comment: @SomeName It does not. You are not getting to the stage when linkage matters

Comment: But they says "linkages of identifiers" not linkages of identifiers referring to object or functions. So I concluded that the concept of linkage can be applied to *any* identifier (not only referring to object or function in which case the identifier has no linkage)