# extern "C" enum in C++ for use in assembly

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I want to have some values defined in a C++ module that I can use in an assembly file. I want this in an enum instead of defining a bunch of integers, so I do not have to keep track of all the specific values.

Currently I am simply using the following (which works just fine):

```cpp
int foo = 0;
int bar = 1;
```

But I want to replace it with an enum:

```cpp
extern "C" enum {
    foo,
    bar
};
```

so that I can use it in an assembly module like this:

```
[EXTERN foo]
...
mov eax, [foo]
...
```

This compiles successfully, but during linking g++ complains:

```
undefined reference to `foo'
```

Is there a way to use an enum for this, or am I forced to use simple integers?

Comment: `enum` is a type it has no storage in memory hence no address to link against.

Comment: (this was going to be an answer).  ## No, there's no way to export enums via linking, they're a source-level thing.

`enum` name -> value mapping only appears in debug info, if anywhere.  It's not something the linker will be able to fill in for you.

You could imagine a system that abused ELF relocation entries like `R_X86_64_32` (32-bit absolute address) to hold enum values instead.  Then `mov eax, foo` would put `0` into `eax`

Comment: `mov eax, [foo]` would be a load from address `0`.  Why would you want that?  That syntax is probably left over from your inefficient version that creates a non-const global variable for every enum value(!!??!?!???), preventing the C compiler from doing constant-propagation or using them as immediates.

Comment: @PeterCordes: the assembly code is for my current version, using integers. The integers are non-const because if I declare them const, the linker once again complains about undefined references.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, you want the compiler to be able to optimize them away, that's my point!  If you're hand-writing asm, obviously efficiency matters.  Anyway, you're not *forced* to use this inefficient way.  But you do need some way to translate the enum to NASM source, or like suggested in the answer to the linked duplicate, use some kind of macro language to create C and asm declarations from one source line.  But NASM doesn't use the C preprocessor, so that exact answer won't work, you'd need to adapt it.  Maybe have a build script that turns a text file into a `.h` or `.asm` include file.

Comment: Enumeration constants are constants and therefore have no linkage. If you are interested in language-lawyer staff this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398736/8990329

Comment: In the days of Microsoft 16 bit compilers, you could have used `h2inc.exe` as part of a make process or build batch file to convert `.h` files for C code to `.inc` files for assembly code. With some toolsets, the linker supports global absolutes (like defines) similar to masm `extern xmpl:abs`, which defines `xmpl` as an absolute value (if it's defined in the current source file, it's a public, otherwise it's an external reference).